# Child window transperency issues

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to create a child window with transparent areas recognized by RGB ( 0, 0, 255 ) in the bitmap which will be drawn all over the child window.

Following is the code that I am using to make it transparent, the problem is that the parent window beneath the transparent parts of the child window too gets transparent and desktop is visible through it.

```
hwndChild = ::CreateWindowEx ( 0, "mycustomwindow", txt.c_str (  ), WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CHILD, x, y, width, height, parent, 0, hInstance, ( LPVOID ) this ) ;

transparent (  );



void transparent (  )
{



    HMODULE hUser32 = GetModuleHandle (  ( "USER32.DLL" )  );



    COLORREF g_ColourKey    = 0xFF00FF;     // 0,0,255(magenta) in RGB hex value


    typedef BOOL ( WINAPI *lpfnSetLayeredWindowAttributes ) ( HWND hWnd, COLORREF crKey, BYTE bAlpha, DWORD dwFlags );
    lpfnSetLayeredWindowAttributes SetLayeredWindowAttributes;

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes = ( lpfnSetLayeredWindowAttributes ) GetProcAddress ( hUser32, "SetLayeredWindowAttributes" );

    if( SetLayeredWindowAttributes == NULL ) 
    {


        MessageBox ( hwndChild, "Error, cannot load window transparency\n REASON: Could not load User32.DLL", "Error!", MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK );


    }
    else
    { 


        DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong ( hwndChild, GWL_STYLE ); 

        dwStyle &= ~( WS_CAPTION | WS_SIZEBOX ); 

        SetWindowLong  ( hwndChild, GWL_STYLE, dwStyle );


        InvalidateRect ( hwndChild, NULL, true ); 

        SetWindowPos   ( hwndChild, NULL, 0, 0, wWidth, wHeight, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER );


        SetWindowLong  ( hwndChild, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong ( hwndChild, GWL_EXSTYLE ) | WS_EX_LAYERED );

        SetLayeredWindowAttributes ( hwndChild, g_ColourKey, 0, LWA_COLORKEY );


    }



};
```

The parent window (which is atop level window) itself is using the same function to make certain parts transparent, with the following dwStyle : WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN

Comment: What OS version? Child windows don't support layering until Windows 8 afaik.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Windows 7... Is there another way to do it ?

Comment: Render the child window to a memory bitmap and then blit it with transparency to the main window.

Comment: @JonathanPotter what if we need mouse events from the child window and child window further have more children ?

Comment: Then it gets complicated :)

Comment: Hmm... Is there a way to get parent window's bitmap/image ? I can paint it over the child window then paint the transparent bitmap on top of it whenever it needs refreshing ?

Comment: Have a look at `WM_PRINTCLIENT`.

Comment: Look at `SetWindowRgn()`.  Child windows support regions.  There are several functions for creating different types of regions. You are likely looking for [`ExtCreateRegion()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162706.aspx). You can translate your RGB data into an `RGNDATA` array to define where your transparent pixels are located within the child window, then create and apply the region to the child window.